# Ellipse 2019-12 is opening bytecode file instead of .java while debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, sap, bytecode, sap-cloud-platform

I'm trying to debug my Java application using Eclipse IDE 2019-12 on the sap cloud platform server

However, when trying to debug my breakpoints the eclipse is opening the bytecode .0101 file

How to make it debug the java file?

[image: l]

Comment: Of which plug-in is this bytecode editor? Probably in the Java Build Path the specification where the source code is located is missing, so that the bytecode editor is used instead of the Java editor. Please show where the `.java` file of the shown class is (in a JAR or in a source folder?) and how  in the Java Build Path it is attached to the corresponding `.class` file.

Comment: How do you start the debugging? What SCP server version do you use? Is it trial or commercial?

Comment: @Suncatcher SCP is commercial, I just right click on server and I click on start server in debugging mode. After deleting all breakpoints , suddenly the problem seems to be resolved, I still haven't figure out the reason but I will post an answer once I find out what happened